# Как подключиться к IIS Web Services на андроид?

Tags: android, wcf, soap, kotlin

Добрый день! Есть задача перевести приложение для Windows CE написанное на C# на платформу Android Java/Kotlin.
На IIS крутится Web Service к которому подключается приложение и передает или получает инфу.
На C# это выглядит так:
В проект добавлена ссылка Web References 
    http://ukr-tst/Aif60/TSDUpdateItemParameters/xppservice.svc
Написан код:

```
TSDUpdateItemParameters.BasicHttpBinding_WMS_TSDUpdateItemParametersService getItemParameters = new TSDUpdateItemParameters.BasicHttpBinding_WMS_TSDUpdateItemParametersService();
TSDUpdateItemParameters.CallContext context = new TSDUpdateItemParameters.CallContext();
context.Company = "tst";
TSDUpdateItemParameters.WMS_TSDUpdateItemParametersContract[] ListItemSize;
getItemParameters.CallContextValue = context;
getItemParameters.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("tst", "tst", "tst");
getItemParameters.PreAuthenticate = true;
getItemParameters.Url = "http://ukr-tst/Aif60/TSDUpdateItemParameters/xppservice.svc";
ListItemSize = getItemParameters.GetItemParameters("55200081");
```

Как сделать что-то подобное на android?

Answer (score 2):

Подобное не получится. Придется весь сетевой слой писать с нуля.
`SOAP` не является родным протоколом `Android`, но сторонние библиотеки есть.
А вот если это `NTLM authentication` у вас, то с этим совсем плохо.

Если приложение большое, может имеет смысл сначала посмотреть на `Xamarin`?

**Если автор все-таки решит потратить время впустую**
С SOAP можно работать например с этим
https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android

NTLM у меня заработало только с помощью
https://github.com/kaey/ntlm
Прикрученного при помощи
https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Mobile

Но все это было не для продакшена.

Comment: У меня по ходу NTLM authentication... Xamarin на текущий момент не вариант...

Comment: Тогда серверную часть лучше переписать или как минимум написать обертку чтобы избавиться от NTLM а лучше еще и от SOAP.

Comment: Серверную часть переписать к сожалению нельзя. А обертку делать не очень хочется...

Comment: Дополню. SOAP тяжёлый прокол. Можно взять готовые SOAP-библиотеки для Java, но несколько лет назад никакой автогенерации для них не было, зато было много ручного кодирования. Можно переписать серверную часть на REST, использовать стандартную аутентификацию, совместимую с OAuth2 и JWT. Тогда упростится и серверный код, и клиентский.

Comment: Я в свое время "воевал" с NTLM на Андроид. Не стоит это того. Готовых библиотек нет, никому это не нужно. Детище Майкрософта, нигде кроме Windows не используется.

Comment: Не то слово - не завидую тому кто будет писать реализацию SOAP - это и в обычной Java было делом не простым, а с Android наверное и вовсе мраки...

Comment: @MarkShevchenko как будто для REST автогенерация есть...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я имел в виду, что кодогенерация для SOAP есть в Visual Studio. Android-приложение придётся писать вручную. И, если писать вручную, то REST гораздо проще для кодирования, чем SOAP.