# проблема с NTLM Auth(kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, soap, retrofit2, okhttp

Столкнулся с проблемой к подключению к веб-сервису, на веб сервисе подключена сетевая аунтификация NTLM, искал информацию по этому вопросу, наткнулся на обсуждения [Support NTLM auth](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/206), но честно говоря не разобрался как это использовать, пытался сделать через basic auth, но также ничего не вышло

```html
class NtlmAuthenticator(private val username: String, private val password: String) :
            Authenticator {

            override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
                val ntlmHeader = response.header("WWW-Authenticate") ?: return null

                if (ntlmHeader.contains("NTLM")) {
                    val credential = Credentials.basic(username,password)
                    return response.request.newBuilder()
                        .header("Authorization", credential)
                        .build()
                }
                return null
            }
        }
```

```html
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .authenticator(NtlmAuthenticator("логин","пароль"))
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build()
```

Получал 401 код и все.

Может кто знает как это можно реализовать, я отправляю SOAP запросы, возможно в хедерах надо что то прописать?
Я использую retrofit2 и okhttp3

Comment: Вот старый топик, проще прокси написать чем клиента: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/738357/184031

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Спасибо за ваш ответ, я уже разобрался с этой проблемой(забыл добавить свой ответ), решал я это с помощью библиотеки [jcifs](https://www.jcifs.org/) и написанного к ней [NTLM аутентификатора](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770581/ntlm-authentication-in-android)